# UserVisibleHint is false on selected ViewPager Fragment managed by FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library, android-pageradapter

I've encountered a really hard to diagnose issue in an Android app. `getUserVisibleHint()` returns `false` on the currently selected fragment in a `ViewPager` when it should return true (because it is visible and selected).

I've characterized the instances I see this behavior as follows:

- Fragment is selected and currently displayed in a `ViewPager`
- ViewPager is managed by a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`
- Fragment was previously selected, its state was saved and later restored by the `PagerAdapter`

  - minimum of 3 tabs in the viewpager
  - user navigates to tab 3, then to tab 1 then back to tab 3.
- App uses Support Library version 24.0.0 or greater

Comment: [Bug Report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38414371)

Answer (score 8):

Debugging revealed that `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is actually setting the state of the selected tab properly in `setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)` but that it is later set to false in `FragmentManager#moveToState(Fragment f, int newState, int transit, int transitionStyle, boolean keepActive)`

```
//from FragmentManager#moveToState(Fragment f, int newState, int transit, int transitionStyle, boolean keepActive)
f.mUserVisibleHint = f.mSavedFragmentState.getBoolean(
        FragmentManagerImpl.USER_VISIBLE_HINT_TAG, true);
```

`f.mSavedFragmentState` above has saved the visible state as `false` because it was saved when the fragment was no longer on the screen.

So the issue here is state loss; the visible state is being set in `FragmentStatePagerAdapter#setPrimaryItem` but is lost some time before the fragment's `onResume` method is called.

#### The Fix

Until this bug is fixed in the library, override `setPrimaryItem` in your `PagerAdapter` and force any pending transactions to commit first.

```
public static class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        //Force any pending transactions to save before we set an item as primary
        finishUpdate(null);
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Page " + (position + 1);
    }
}
```

To fix this, `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` must commit any fragment transactions before setting the user visible hint.

#### `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Just to show what's happening inside `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // If we already have this item instantiated, there is nothing
    // to do.  This can happen when we are restoring the entire pager
    // from its saved state, where the fragment manager has already
    // taken care of restoring the fragments we previously had instantiated.
    if (mFragments.size() > position) {
        Fragment f = mFragments.get(position);
        if (f != null) {
            return f;
        }
    }

    if (mCurTransaction == null) {
        mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    }

    Fragment fragment = getItem(position);
    if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Adding item #" + position + ": f=" + fragment);
    if (mSavedState.size() > position) {
        Fragment.SavedState fss = mSavedState.get(position);
        if (fss != null) {
            fragment.setInitialSavedState(fss);
        }
    }
    while (mFragments.size() <= position) {
        mFragments.add(null);
    }
    fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
    fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
    mFragments.set(position, fragment);
    mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment)object;
    if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
        if (mCurrentPrimaryItem != null) {
            mCurrentPrimaryItem.setMenuVisibility(false);
            mCurrentPrimaryItem.setUserVisibleHint(false);
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.setMenuVisibility(true);
            fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);
        }
        mCurrentPrimaryItem = fragment;
    }
}

@Override
public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
    if (mCurTransaction != null) {
        mCurTransaction.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
        mCurTransaction = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Got the same bug with appcompat-v7:25.3.1. Your fix works, thanks.

Comment: I have the new version (`27.0.2`) after being marked as fixed by the google team, but the problem still happening and I tried your fix and still happening..! any help..?

Comment: @AlaaAbuZarifa `27.0.2` was released in November 2017. The [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38414371) marked this issue fixed in late February 2018. I would expect that it is fixed in `27.1.1` but I have not tested this version.

Answer (score 1):

If it is compatible with your project, try version `27.1.1` (or newer) of the support library. The [related bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38414371) was marked fixed in late February 2018 and version `27.1.1` was released in April 2018.

Comment: I am using support lib version `27.1.1` and still getting this issue, will try your solution and update accordingly.

Comment: Your solution fixes this issue, however going through the code I see that [`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` V13](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter) has been deprecated since `27.1.0` and instead suggests to use [`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` V4](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter) which seems to work only with V4 support Fragments. Is *this* the dev's fix? Use V4 Fragments instead.